# How to grant read ,write and create access on a all tables in a database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to give access to a role and it should be able to create schemas, create tables, Materialized views ..etc. He should be able to do everything related to the  database.

How to achieve this?

Thanks,

Xi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Make the role the owner of the database
2. Grant the role the specific permissions you want it to have